# Taking multiple images when Camera is triggered

Tags: python, sensor

I have some code that when the PIR Sensor is triggered the camera takes one single images and uploads it to Azure blob storage, taking one single photo is not sufficient but I can't get the Program to take multiple images when the camera is triggered. This is the code I have so far

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from picamera import PiCamera
from datetime import datetime
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings

camera = PiCamera()
pir = MotionSensor()
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='YOURACCOUNT', account_key='YOURKEY')

while True:
pir.wait_for_motion()
filename = "pircam-" +  datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.jpg")
camera.capture(filename)
pir.wait_for_no_motion()
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
'YOURCONTAINER',
filename,
filename,
content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='image/jpeg'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would change your functions to be pir.isThereMotion() that returns true/false  then you could do

```
while true:
    if pir.isThereMotion():
        filename = "pircam-" +  datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.jpg")
        camera.capture(filename)
        time.sleep(1)
        ....
```

This way it will just take a picture ever second while motion is detected, no need to wait for it to start and wait for it to stop.

but using what you have now, you could just loop on the lines that capture/save an image a certain number of times

```
while True:
    pir.wait_for_motion()
    for x in range(numberOfPicturesYouWantToTake):
        filename = "pircam-" +  datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.jpg")
        camera.capture(filename)
        time.sleep(1)
        ...
```

Comment: I'll try this out, Thanks for the response.